# Telling Amazon's s3-log-service to create log files with the reduced redundancy storage class

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a bucket which contains only log files and I want all files in this bucket to use the reduced redundancy storage class.

My first try was to define a bucket policy. But as far as I can see those policies can only be used to restrict any access to the bucket contents. It seems to lack some hock functionality to modify the write access of the s3-log-service.

Is there any other way to tell the s3-log-service to use the reduced redundancy storage class?

Answer (score 2):

Reduced redundancy is set *per object* when it is created and therefor you cannot apply a bucket policy. To make use of this feature, you have to add a header (`x-amz-storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY`) when writing the object to S3.

I'm not super familiar with the logging facility but from what I can tell it seems like you would have to do this yourself.

Since your files are already in a bucket on S3, you will have to use a `COPY` to set the new header. The technical steps (high-level) to do this [are outlined in the documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ChgStoClsOfObj.html), if you let me know what language you usually write code in, I can try to help you with that and extend my answer.

Comment: I do not know what files are created by the s3-log-service. Following your suggestion would mean, that I have to poll the bucket every minute to see if anything has newly created. And I am not sure if I can copy a file to itself to change the storage class.

Comment: You could use SNS. You can setup a notification whenever something is added to the bucket.

Comment: I just checked with the PHP SDK, I can copy files over itself – only changing the headers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to let logs upload in `STANDARD` storage class, but then to add Lifecycle Rule that will move object to `REDUCED_REDUNDANCY` storage class, like described in the answer about [Default Storage Class for S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45847873/38592). You should not waste too much money through the initial 30 days (while `STANDARD` class is active) and transition to desired storage class should not be rather cheap as well.

If you do loose to much money still, then providing storage class during initial upload request is the way to go. See the answer about the way to [specify/enforce storage class for S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50639286/38592).