# How to change Default Storage Class on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

By default storage in a bucket is STANDARD. And while pushing each object we can change the storage.

But is there a way to change default storage at Bucket level ( probably through AWS Console) ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's technically true that you cannot set the storage class on a per-bucket basis. However, you can specify a lifecycle policy on your bucket to automatically transition new objects to a storage class, as it says [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/).

> The Standard - IA storage class is set at the object level and can
>   exist in the same bucket as Standard, allowing you to use lifecycle
>   policies to **automatically transition objects between storage
>   classes** without any application changes.

To do this, go to the Management tab for a your bucket and click 'Add lifecycle rule'
[image: Add lifecycle rule]

Give it a name and click next. For 'Configure transition', select current version. Click Add transition, choose "Transition to Standard-IA after" and choose 30, because 30 is the minimum. Finish your rule and you are all set.

[image]

Comment: does this transition incur (extra) costs? (i.e. as if requests was made on these objects)

Comment: It does, and it can sneak up on you really quick. Ranges from $0.01 to $0.05 per 1000 transition requests.

Comment: It's better to set the policy in your PUT request rather than using a lifecycle policy due to the request costs.

Comment: Yes, the costs of these request often are more than the hosting cost saving (!!) - best to do this during upload.

Answer (score 12):

The storage class cannot be set on a per-bucket basis. It must be specified with each upload operation in your client.

Comment: It is possible to pass extra header in object upload request (PUT Object, POST Object, and Initiate Multipart Upload):

x-amz-storage-class: STANDARD_IA

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-howtoset

Comment: Has this situation changed at all in the past decade? - seems like setting a Storage Class for a bucket would be such an obvious thing...

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to specify storage class in upload request (PUT Object, POST Object, and Initiate Multipart Upload) via `x-amz-storage-class` header.

Additionally, if you want to enforce some storage classes in a bucket, you can do this via Bucket Policy (with `s3:x-amz-storage-class` condition key). This way any attempt to upload object with prohibited classes would fail.

Thus, you should do:

1. Specify allowed storage class in Upload Operation (see details about [`x-amz-storage-class` header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-howtoset)).
2. (optionally) Set `s3:x-amz-storage-class` key condition-based Bucket Policy (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866257/38592)).

Comment: I found this a great addition to a program that was able to upload to AWS but was hiding the Deep Glacier option (likely, for paid version). I have specified this and it started to go to GDA Storage class right away.