# Policy enforcing S3 standard storage class

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is there a way to define a S3 bucket policy to enforce standard storage class? I want to prevent users from creating objects with reduced redundancy storage class.

Answer (score 6):

You can now use a condition in an S3 bucket policy to constrain the creation of S3 objects (using `PutObject`) to specific storage classes.

The current version of the AWS documentation has an example - [Restrict object uploads to objects with a specific storage class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#example-storage-class-condition-key).

> Suppose Account A owns a bucket and the account administrator wants to restrict Dave, a user in Account A, to be able to only upload objects to the bucket that will be stored with the `STANDARD_IA` storage class. The Account A administrator can accomplish this by using the `s3:x-amz-storage-class` condition key as shown in the following example bucket policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "statement1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA-ID:user/Dave"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-storage-class": [
            "STANDARD_IA"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Your values for `Principal` and `Resource` would be specific to your users and S3 bucket(s). The `Condition` constraint would need to change to `STANDARD`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, at least it doesn't seem to be documented - given the [Amazon IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) policy design, this constraint would need to be covered by a resp. [Condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition):

> The Condition element (or Condition block) lets you specify conditions
>   for when a policy is in effect. [...] Condition values can include date, time, the IP
>   address of the requester, the ARN of the request source, the user
>   name, user ID, and the user agent of the requester. Some services let
>   you specify additional values in conditions; **for example, Amazon S3
>   lets you write a condition using the s3:VersionId key, which is unique
>   to that service**. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

Now, section *Amazon S3 Condition Keys for Object Operations* within [Specifying Conditions in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html) lacks any reference to the storage class, whereas the semantic sibling `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption` is present already:

> When granting the s3:PutObject permission, the bucket owner can add a
>   condition using this key to require the user to specify this header in
>   the request. A bucket owner can grant such conditional permission to
>   ensure that objects the user uploads are saved encrypted.

Given the involved symmetry for these headers (see section *System-Defined Metadata* within [Object Key and Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)), you might want to simply try `s3:x-amz-storage-class` though, maybe you are lucky and it is in 'private beta' already ;)