# Cost efficient way of changing storage class on an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am aware of this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45847873/2409793) about an indirect way to change the storage class of an S3 bucket.

However, the above solution does not elaborate on whether the

> lifecycle policies to automatically transition objects between storage classes

incur any additional cost.

I am assuming it does, since a lifecycle-based transition incorporates requests to the objects.

So my question is

What is the **most cost-efficient way** of transitioning a bucket (containing millions of small objects) to standard infrequent access storage class?

I assume there is no magic console button that does that for a bucket (and **all** of its contents).

Is the solution based on lifecycle rule cost optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifecycle Transition requests **do** incur additional costs. The pricing is listed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) under "Requests and data retrievals" tab -> "Lifecycle Transition requests (per 1,000 requests)" column.

Whether it's the most cost-efficient way to do it depends on how many objects you have and the average size of your object. You can obtain an [S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) report, do some SQL queries on it and do the math yourself in order to make a wise decision.

Just a rule of thumb that I personally use, if the average size of your object is below 50KB, it's probably not a good idea to transition them to SIA. Instead, I would suggest batching them first before transitioning them to SIA.